# How can I store multiple values per key in a hash table using Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap

In javascript, I have a hash map of key value pairs like:

```
"team", "aemt"
"meat", "aemt"
"car", "acr"
```

And I want to store all of the matching values with the length of the string like this:

```
{4, {"team","meat"}}
{3, {"car"}
```

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: The example you provided is not a valid Object. Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This looks like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please tell us what you need that for. Also, please show us the code you've tried, this should be a fairly trivial task.

Comment: basically, I want to store a key value table that has a key (the length of the word), and a value (an array of the words that are anagrams).  I want to be able to go through the hash map that I have and add values to this new table

Comment: Ah I see, you're storing the word and an anagram of the word. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm storing the word, and the alphabetically sorted version of that word

Comment: Now, I want to go through my list, and find the sorted words that match, and add their word to a new list

Comment: Does that make sense?  Sorry if I'm not explaining it well!

Comment: Okay, so you want to find a word with a specific length and retrieve the word itself and the alphabetically sorted version?

Comment: So basically you have a set of words and want to partition it into groups of words that consist of the same letters?

Comment: Yes, Bergi that's exactly what I need to do.  My output needs to list the anagram sets

Comment: Ah, so your key would be the alphabetically sorted version and your value would be an array of words matching it.

Comment: yup! That's what I need Jon

Comment: Okay, so how would your function look to find an anagram? What would be the input? A word, an alphabetically sorted word, something else?

Comment: The input would be an alphabetically sorted word, so I can check against the other parts of the array to find matches.  But how do I put it in a data structure such that I can keep adding matches?

Answer (score 2):

Dividing your sets by length should not be necessary, the hashing algorithm should be able to take care of that itself. It would only be advisable if you're going to sort your words by length.

> store multiple values per key in a hash table

You cannot. However, you can store an array of strings for each key.

```
var words = ["team", "meat", "car"],
    map = {};
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    var key = words[i].toLowercase().split('').sort().join('');
    if (key in map)
        map[key].push(words[i]);
    else
        map[key] = [ words[i] ];
}
```

Comment: What would the javascript code look like for storing an array of strings for each key?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Just put an array as each value, and push to it when it already exists.

Comment: `hash2 = {};
    var count = 0;
    for (i in hash1){
        for (j in hash1){
            if (i!=j && hash1[i] == hash1[j])
                console.log("match!");
                hash2[count].push(hash1[i]);
        }
        count++;
    }`

Comment: Oops, sorry that looks terrible

Comment: @ZachLucas: You might [put the code into your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19149496/edit) as well. Please also include there how you're constructing `hash1`